# Left sided subscript with \mel of physics package

Tags: brackets, physics

I want to tex the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[
amsmath,
onecolumn,
aps,
prb,
notitlepage,
10pt
]{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{physics}

\newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
\newcommand{\eps}{\epsilon}

\begin{document}

\begin{align}
\abs{ _u\mel{\nu,\vb*{0}}{\vb*{k}\cdot\vb*{p}}{\nu',\vb*{0}}_u }^2
\end{align}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

The problem is in the that the u in front of the matrix element (`\mel` is from the physics package) is too far away from the left bracket (<). Can I somehow reduce that space?

Comment: Will `_u\!\mel` do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A solution using [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools):

```
\documentclass{revtex4-1}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\DeclarePairedDelimiterX\phys[3]{\langle}{\rangle}{#1 \delimsize\vert\mathopen{} #2 \delimsize\vert\mathopen{} #3}
\newcommand*\Vector[1]{\boldsymbol{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \abs*{\prescript{}{u}{\phys*{\nu,\Vector{0}}{\Vector{k} \cdot \Vector{p}}{\nu',\Vector{0}}}_{u}}^{2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

For your particular problem, the `\prescript` macro is the key.

Comment: Remember if say `#2` is shown with a sign, then `\delimsize\vert #2` ends up with the wrong spacing around the sign. See `\phys{-1}{-1}{-1}`. You may need `\vert\mathopen{}`.

Comment: @daleif It's actually taken from p. 64 in your manual (sidebemærkning 3.26). `:)` (I've now changed the code; thank you.)

Comment: I know, the latex book has not been updated for a while. Though I did update it in the `mathtools` manual.

Comment: @daleif Are you planning on making any further updates to your book?

Comment: Sure, I just haven't released them yet. And also, when you work with LaTeX all day long, one want to do something else when you get home. So progress comes in spikes.